# Creating a simple java hash server

Tags: java, sockets

Is it possible to create a simple server in Java that returns a response based on a given key?

So it would be a simple program, that stores a hashmap and returns the result based on a key provided by the client.

What would be the fasted implementation, to have it over HTTP or a socket?   The client will be a web based application.

Comment: Fastest in terms of development time or execution time?

Comment: If we're running by the usual definition of "web-based" as something running within a browser, then you can't do non-HTTP sockets, unless you go with Flash or something like that. AFAIK, you can't get sockets from JavaScript.

Comment: Another angle on "fastest" - for what volume of traffic? It's relatively easy to have a single server which owns the hashmap, but gets much more "fun" if you need to scale beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

No should describe your environment a little better in order to get a qualified answer.
Client is a web based application, thats all we know.

You could provide a servlet and add your hashcode as a request parameter. The servlet will do a lookup and return the requested object using [JSON](http://www.json.org/), this can be parsed in your web based application from javascript.

A tutorial for [prototype](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_json_tutorial.htm)
and one for [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) (which seems more popular).